# Какой частью речи и членом предложения выступает слово "значит"?

Tags: морфология

Вот такое предложение:
Жить - значит быть счастливым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Справочник по пунктуации**:
*значит*
связка, союз, вводное слово, в значении сказуемого

1. Связка. То же, что «это, есть». Присоединяет сказуемое к подлежащему. Перед словом «значит» ставится тире.
   Понять человека – значит простить. Ждать официального разрешения – значит потерять время.
2. Союз. То же, что «и поэтому, следовательно». Соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного. Запятая ставится только перед союзом.
   Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь. Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав.
   Часть двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит». Запятая ставится на стыке главного и придаточного предложения.
   Если встретиться нам не придется, значит такова наша судьба. Если я это сказал, значит я увлекся.
3. Вводное слово. Указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения. То же, что «стало быть, выходит». Выделяется запятыми.
   Село, значит, наше – Радово, // Дворов, почитай, два ста. // Тому, кто его оглядывал, // Приятственны наши места. С. Есенин, Анна Снегина...

Итак, в Вашем примере "значит" - это связка, присоединяет сказуемое к подлежащему. Членом предложения не является. Некоторые лингвисты  "значит" в подобных примерах определяют как частицу.